# Capturing a custom event in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I know how promises and callbacks work in node js but I am very confused about how to capture custom events. 
Let's say I have a global variable x

```
 var x = 10
```

Some asynchronus functions in the event loop update value of x. 
How can I capture variable x having a particular value? Like what should I do when I want to run a function

```
    foo()
```

when variable x attain a value of let's say 50?

Comment: Can you tell how the value of x is being modified either by synchronous function or asynchronous function?

Comment: x is being modified asynchronously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a function to set the variable:

```
var x = 10;

function setX(value) {
    x = value;

    if (x === 50) {
        foo();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can apply a check before calling a function like :

```
var num = 5;

function yourFunction(pass_value) {
    num  = num + pass_value; //your condition

   num == 50 && foo();    //it will only call when num = 50
}
```